# How to repeat values for different variables in cases with the same ID in R

Tags: r, database, na

I want to repeat the information of these variables in the spaces with NA and that they have the same IDs. This an outlook of the actual structure data. (The identifiers are in the columns id1 to id4):

```
id1<-rep(3,8)
id2<-c(rep(1,3),rep(2,4),3)
id3<-rep(1,8)
id4<-c(rep(1,3),rep(2,4),3)
v1<-c(1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,2)
v2<-c(3,NA,NA,5,NA,NA,NA,1)
v3<-c(4,3,4,5,4,2,1,1)
v4<-c(4,8,2,5,4,3,1,1)
data.frame(id1,id2,id3,id4,v1,v2,v3,v4)
```

This is the visualization:

```
> data.frame(id1,id2,id3,id4,v1,v2,v3,v4)
  id1 id2 id3 id4 v1 v2 v3 v4
1   3   1   1   1  1  3  4  4
2   3   1   1   1 NA NA  3  8
3   3   1   1   1 NA NA  4  2
4   3   2   1   2  1  5  5  5
5   3   2   1   2 NA NA  4  4
6   3   2   1   2 NA NA  2  3
7   3   2   1   2 NA NA  1  1
8   3   3   1   3  2  1  1  1
```

How can I fill the NA values with the infomation in the first line of each case by ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(across(starts_with('id'))) %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., is.na(.), first(.)))) %>%
   ungroup
```

---

Or use `fill`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(across(starts_with('id'))) %>% 
  fill(everything())
```

Comment: How can I apply the filling only to certain columns in the data frame?

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez you can use either index i.e. `group_by(across(1:4))` or `group_by(across(id1:id4))` as a range or even `group_by(id1, id2, id3, id4)`

Comment: How can I save the result from the second option? Because when I load the dataframe, it has  the values with NA and it does not keep the filling

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez  You can assign i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(....` regarding the NA, if it is at the top, then use `fill(everything(), .direction = "downup")`